# How do I use this PHP library to access OpenGraph data in a child theme?

Tags: php, post-formats, open-graph

I'm fleshing out post formats in a child theme. For **link**-type posts, if a featured image hasn't been set, I'd like to fetch the OpenGraph image associated with the link and display it.

I've found scottmac's [opengraph PHP library](https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph), which I assume would allow me to get that OpenGraph data. But how would I go about incorporating that into my child theme and using it? I assume it's not as simple as placing `opengraph.php` in my child theme's directory, since that doesn't really make sense, but I don't know what actually *does* make sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much harder then you thought.

1. Copy the library somewhere into your child directory
2. Include the file with `include` or `include_once` PHP function in the child's functions.php file (use `get_stylesheet_directory` function for getting path of the child theme)
3. Use the library how you want